# C++ Programming Assignment dealing with large integer values

Tags: c++

So this assignment I have to do for my C++ class is essentially to prove we can deal with creating classes and operator overloading. Now we have to overload functions +, *, +=, *=, ==, !=, <, <=, >, >=, a binary function of ^ (Hyperint is the class for this assignment) We have to build a constructor: () and input output stream, and prefix/postfix. Now I have built my header file for all of these operator overloading:

```
class Hyperint
{
public:
Hyperint(void);
~Hyperint(void);


const Hyperint & operator+= (const Hyperint & right);
const Hyperint & operator*= (const Hyperint & right);
const Hyperint operator^ (long e) const;
const Hyperint &operator++ (int);
const Hyperint &operator-- (int);


friend const bool operator== (const Hyperint &left, const Hyperint &right);
friend const bool operator!= (const Hyperint &left, const Hyperint &right);
friend const bool operator< (const Hyperint &left, const Hyperint &right);
friend const bool operator<= (const Hyperint &left, const Hyperint &right);
friend const bool operator> (const Hyperint &left, const Hyperint &right);
friend const bool operator>= (const Hyperint &left, const Hyperint &right);
friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, Hyperint & hypint);
friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const Hyperint & hypint);



};

const Hyperint operator+ (const Hyperint & left, const Hyperint &right);
const Hyperint operator* (const Hyperint & left, const Hyperint &right);
```

Now the I'm having several design issues. Because the constructor is calling to type long, type long can only handle because long can only handle integers from: -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647, its clear that the value my professor wants us to deal with 313^313 cannot be held(NOTE: my teacher specifically said that the constructor must accept long variables as arguments). Now the question I have is how can I calculate a value that big, I was thinking of perhaps converting the long as a string and dealing with the number that way, but I'm not sure if that is appropriate for this design. Or I was even thinking of somehow storing the number into pieces into a vector. My question essentially is which design format do you guys think would be best suited for this kind of project? Like how could I add two Hyperint numbers together? Thanks a lot, any help is much appreciated! OH and last quick question, my teacher also said we need to have a "conversion to bool" I'm not entirely sure what he means by this? if you have any ideas it would be great! thanks again!

Comment: BY THE WAY, I forgot to mention that I can't use any external libraries I have to use the STL library. I realize there's external libraries for this exact thing.. THANKS!

Comment: Storing the number using a vector is probably your best bet -- strings are too unwieldy (they're meant for storing text, not numbers). I don't think your professor meant that you should exclusively have a constructor that accepts `long` -- also, are you sure he/she didn't mean `long long` on Windows? Conversion to bool is so that you can write `Hyperint h(0); if (!h) cout << "zero\n";`.

Comment: You aren't showing us enough of your header. Specifically you don't give us ANY of the information related to your actual problem which has to do with the constructor and longs.  Separately your signatures don't make sense in terms of const-correctness for your return parameters.  You shouldn't return const values it makes no sense, even your const reference returns make no sense.

Comment: @UpAndAdam in this case my prof said explicitly for operator overloading this method of using const is what should be done.. To be completely honest I'm not entirely sure why, I'm still learning. But thank you I'll try and fix this.

Comment: so basically he just wants to see if you can implement the functionality and you didn't build the header yourself then?

Comment: I still don't see a constructor in your header that takes a long :-p I only see a no-operator constructor

Comment: @UpAndAdam The header no not really, he wants us to control the operations i think, and i just made my constructor, well I'm working on it... essentially type hyperint will be equivalent to a vector<int>

Comment: No I'm saying in the header you have above, the only constructor you have doesn't take any arguments at all.  You should add one that says `Hyperint(long);` if he requires you to have a constructor from a long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your teacher is calling a `Hyperint` is merely an arbitrary number of decimal or binary digits.  You can store as many of those digits as you like in an array or vector, and then perform grade school arithmetic on them.

To illustrate, consider the following [multiplication operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm):

```
        23958233
            5830 ×
    ------------
        00000000 ( =      23,958,233 ×     0)
       71874699  ( =      23,958,233 ×    30)
     191665864   ( =      23,958,233 ×   800)
    119791165    ( =      23,958,233 × 5,000)
    ------------
    139676498390 ( = 139,676,498,390        )
```

So you have two operands: 23958233 and 5830.  Assuming a node graph shaped like a singly-linked list (for illustrative purposes), the decimal digits of each operand would be stored in your vector like this:

```
2 --> 3 --> 9 --> 5 --> 8 --> 2 --> 3 --> 3
```

and

```
5 --> 9 --> 8 --> 8
```

In other words, each element in your vector will store a single decimal digit, and each vector will store a single complete number.  You will store the intermediate results in a similar way (one vector for each intermediate result), and then add them all together, grade-school style.

Note that this just illustrates a *single multiplication operation.*  For raising numbers to a power, you'll have to repeat this multiplication for however many times the power says.

Comment: my only question and for the record thank you it helped, although I'm thinking about how to implement this, and my first idea was to for example 514^29, was to store 514 in the vector 29 times. Although, if I wanted to add two Hyperints together, this would cause issues obviously.. Do you have any comments about this idea or am I just not on the right path haha

Comment: Unless you want to get into logarithms, multiplying the number by itself the number of times specified in the exponent is probably the most straightforward way.  This won't of course, work for fractional exponents, but I assume your teacher doesn't need to see an implementation for that.

Comment: but multiplying the number by itself would generate a number that would not be accurate, for example 313^313 would give me a negative number obviously. I don't think I understand necessarily what you mean, thank you!

Comment: Why would it give you a negative number?  Remember, you're not using `long` or `long long` for this; you're using a vector of numeric digits.  Multiplying two positive numbers always results in a positive number, unless you overflow a signed integer.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was assuming, just multiplying 313, 313 times of a long long, gave me a negative number. So just to completely understand what you're explaining is that each position in the vector would store the value of each exponent, for example 514^20, the 8th position would be the last 7 positions multiplied by 514? I'm sorry I'm not quite grasping the concept.. but thank you

Comment: wow i just had the biggest urika moment, wow thank you so much that makes this so much easier, i was trying to do too much. Over thinking, my biggest issue... Haha thank you soo much!

Comment: last quick question, does my header file look right? I don't wanna have a stupid mistake like that... Thank you, I owe you a beer... or 17... haha

Comment: It's unclear to me why you would have `const` in method parameters, but I'm not a C++ expert.

Comment: @drocktapiff The header is quite OK. There is one unsuaul thing, for parameterless functions/methods you don't have to specify `(void)` in C++. In C you specify `(void)` for parameterless functions because otherwise parameterless functions are vararg by default but this isn't true in C++ so you can omit `(void)`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The `constant` in the method parameters state that his function won't modify the arguments which are passed by reference, which allows his function to handle both constant and non-constant inputs.  The const for the `operator ^` method states that the operation won't modify data that isn't marked mutable, so that the method may be used on a 'const Hyperint' :-)  The part I raised earlier regarded the return types.  Great explanation by the way